# Run ASP.NET Entity Framework 6 stored procedure asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, asynchronous, entity-framework-6

I am trying to build a page that allows the user to kick off a stored procedure and then continue to use the rest of the site without having to wait for that process to complete.
I have tried creating a background worker thread and a secondary EDMX just for this call, but currently the site is still just unresponsive while the code runs (takes one to two minutes usually).

```
    protected void SaveReversal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PeriodList.SelectedValue != "")
        {
            var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(AsyncReverseDataload_DoWork);
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
            bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
            bw.RunWorkerAsync(Convert.ToInt32(PeriodList.SelectedValue));
        }
    }

    private void AsyncReverseDataload_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int TrackerDetailKey = (int)e.Argument;
        using (AsyncEntities ar = new AsyncEntities())
        {
            IObjectContextAdapter dbcontextadapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)ar;
            dbcontextadapter.ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 600;

            try
            {
                var results = ar.ReverseDataload(TrackerDetailKey);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I get this actually running so that the site remains responsive to the user after starting the execution of the stored procedure?

Comment: Make the method async?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you say that it can take one or two minutes you are in a "Fire and forget" situation (at leas I think so).

Here are some options :
-ThreadPool using Task.Run, Task.Factory.StartNew  etc. However, I really think this is a bad idea!
IIS/ASP.NET has to recycle the application. If background thread is running when this recycling takes place,that work will be lost.

-QueueBackgroundWorkItem , use this if your task goes up to 30 seconds

-IRegisteredObject which is a background worker + a last chance

-third party libraries
"HangFire"
Nito.AspNetBackgroundTasks package , check the [github](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks) page how to use it.

-calling a method out of page scope, that is from a asmx/wcf, maybe embedded in project.

besides all of these I would go for a **Reliable Solution** which is 
-Console app or 
-Service , on which tasks could be added from you WebApp directly in the "Tasks Queue" and then executed safely from there with logs and necessary logic.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, there was a lot of good information in there! I ended up spinning the work off into a WCF service with IsOneWay set to true. The page calls it and then lets the user continue to use the rest of the site as normal.